# How do I delete a specific column when generating an output file in HDFS from Logstash?

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hdfs, logstash, elastic-stack

I use Logstash to store local log data in HDFS.
and load hive table using hive external table function.

Logstash adds timestamp and version information to output(HDFS, Elastic...).

But, I need not timestamp and version, because just using `logstash` to ETL.

So I want deleting fields such as timestamp, version information.

log data is like this

```
$ cat /$PATH/log.txt
[data] [data2] [data3]
[data] [data2] [data3]
[data] [data2] [data3]
```

and HDFS Output file is like this

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /$PATH/log.txt
[timestamp] [version] [data] [data2] [data3]
[timestamp] [version] [data] [data2] [data3]
[timestamp] [version] [data] [data2] [data3]
```

How can i make output HDFS file format like this?

```
$ hadoop fs -cat /$PATH/log.txt
[data] [data2] [data3]
[data] [data2] [data3]
[data] [data2] [data3]
```

Comment: If you want to modify your .txt file in HDFS (and it's not too long), you could use awk. Something like this: `hadoop fs -cat log.txt | awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $3))}'` (I assume that your columns are separated by a blank space)

Comment: If you're using the webhdfs output plugin, have you tried the message_format parameter?